# Raspicast don't work on my Raspberry 4

Tags: raspbian, remote

I have tried to make my Raspberry behave like a Chromecast, following tutorials like this one: [Raspberry Pi Chromecast Alternative using Raspicast](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-chromecast/)

There are lot of other tutorials, but they have all the same steps, basically install omxplayer/omxiv on Raspberry, enable SSH, and download Raspicast.

I have followed those steps, but when I try to cast a video or an image via the application, nothing happens.

My Raspberry is a Raspberry 4, running on Raspbian, connected to network with Wi-Fi.

SHH work well, as I can connect to Raspberry with Putty.

What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Check the logs in folder `/var/log` or look for the `omxplayer.log` and check it out.

Comment: I can't find any logs...

Answer (score 0):

As I checked about this a couple months ago, [omxiv](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/omxiv) source files are destined for Raspberry Pi 2 firmware which comes with [ilclient](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/libs/ilclient) binary, needed to compile omxiv.

I handled to make a fresh firmware install on a Raspberry Pi 2, and the problem now comes from [Raspicast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.huber.raspicast) application, which seems not been maintained and YouTube links are not been sent in a way omxiv can handle them anymore.