# Raspicast: Google Chromecast on Raspbian

Tags: retropie, chromecast

OS: RetroPie 4.7
I want to use my Raspberry Pi as a Chromecast stick and followed this tutorial:
https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-As-Chromecast-Alternative-Raspicast/

When i enter the 'git clone' command
`git clone https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/omxiv`
the Pi asks me to enter my credentials for Github. However, that is not part of this tutorial or any others i found. Even if i log in with an existing acount the Pi refuses to download the repository, saying i dont have access to it.

Does anyone know how i can get it to download the github stuff?

Comment: odd - I don't get asked for credentials from github - you could just download the zip of course from github

Comment: Note: this won't make your raspberry pi a chromecast device - so, it's not really "Google Chromecast on Raspbian" at all

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to copy the exact link from the Github page - the way to use for a non-Github user should be HTTPS link provided there, as in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of github repository]

But as [I answered](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/140773/26774) the question, [Raspicast don't work on my Raspberry 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108440/26774), the [Raspicast app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.huber.raspicast) to cast to your Raspberry Pi omxiv seems is not been maintained (at least at the moment).